# hideSheet() in Google AppScript not hiding sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where I'm trying to hide two tabs:

```
function mySheet() {
// lots of stuff
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data").showSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data").hideSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").showSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").hideSheet();
}
```

Weirdly, "Template" gets hidden but "Raw Data" doesn't. I added the showSheet() method based on an answer to another question but it didn't make any difference.

What could be causing the hideSheet() method to not work? I checked spelling. The "Raw Data" sheet is active at times during the script execution and should be hidden at the end of the function call to mySheet().

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: I think that your script is correct. So, about `I checked spelling.`, I'm worried that in your situation, the issue except for spelling might be related to your current issue. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation of `"Template" gets hidden but "Raw Data" doesn't.`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
function mySheet() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet0").showSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet0").hideSheet();
}
```